# Firebase orderbychild().equalto() showing null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my JSON Structure:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "userKey1" : {
      "deviceToken" : "deviceTokenID",
      "displayName" : "Name here",
      "dob" : "28/6/2017",
      "email" : "efg@wxy.com",
      "gender" : "M"
   },
    "userKey2" : {
      "deviceToken" : "deviceTokenID",
      "displayName" : "Name here",
      "dob" : "28/1/2017",
      "email" : "abc@xyz.com",
      "gender" : "M",
    }
  }
}
```

In my android Firebase file, I type this:

```
Query findUser = mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo("abc@xyz.com");
findUser.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.i("findUser","Snapshot: " + dataSnapshot.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I get the following log:

```
06-28 22:06:50.190 30962-30962/in.sample.project I/findUser: Snapshot: DataSnapshot { key = users, value = null }
```

I do not know why I am getting null when cleary I have a child who's email node matches "abc@xyz.com".

Answer (score 1):

You need a foreach loop to get the user in your findUser query because your query contains a collection.

```
Query findUser = mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo("abc@xyz.com");
```

put this part in your eventlistener
....

```
public Iterable<DataSnapshot> getChildren (){

       for (DataSnapshot child : parent.getChildren()) { 
            ....
       }
}
```

Comment: .once() is for JS. I am using Android. It shows an error.

Comment: I used findUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent() and I managed to get the user data. The problem is that the key is the userID and the data (along with all the children) is stored under snapshot.value() Now the question is, how can I loop all the children in the snapshot.value()'s json?

Comment: ok. finally i checked your android documentation and found something interesting. check this update

Comment: and how do you do it for JS again ?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add security rules.

```
rules: {
"users" : {
      ".indexOn": "email",
    }
}
```

I guess, that did the trick. Hope it helps someone. :)

Comment: Why the downvote? This solved my problem, and I put it out here for others to know.